# How to set the div to take the space to the end of the container?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have section that has few elements inside. They are all on the same line/row. I used div elements combined with CSS to put all elements next to each other. I'm not sure if this is the best practice to layout the elements and I'm open to suggestions. My problem is message box that is triggered if user didn't meet search criteria. Field box is set to `display:none`. After user clicks on the `Search` if message shows up everything shifts to the left. I'm wondering if message can expand to the right side of the screen instead of pushing elements to the left? Also I'm wondering how that would affect smaller screen and what would be the best option in that case?

```js
$('#searchBtn').on('click',searchFun);

function searchFun(){
  var menuVal = $.trim($('#menu').val()),
 searchFldVal = $.trim($('#searchFld').val());
  
  if(!searchFldVal){
  $('#searchMsg').addClass("error").show().text('This field is required.').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow').queue(function(){
      $(this).removeClass("error").dequeue();
  });
 }else if(searchFldVal.length < 3){
  $('#searchMsg').addClass("error").show().text('You must enter at least 3 characters to search on.').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow').queue(function(){
      $(this).removeClass("error").dequeue();
  });
 }else{
    console.log('Search record.');
  }
}
```

```css
section.mainBox{
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 0;
 background-color: white;
 border: 2px solid #000099;
}
div#Container {
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #B0C4DE;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
}
div.nextTo {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
span.msgMainBox {
 display:none; 
 margin: 2px 5px; 
 padding:2px 25px 2px 35px;
}
span.error {
 border: 1px solid;
 margin: 5px;
 padding:5px 10px 5px 40px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 10px center;
 border-radius: 3px;
 display: block;
}
span.error {
 color: #D8000C;
 background-color: #FFBABA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="mainBox">
  <div id="Container">
    <div class="nextTo">
      <select name="menu" id="menu">
        <option value="1">Name</option>
        <option value="2">DOB</option>
        <option value="3">City</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="nextTo">
      <input type="text" name="searchFld" id="searchFld" size="24" maxlength="24" value="" title="Maximum size of the field is 24 characters." placeholder="Example: Marco Polo" />
    </div>
    <div class="nextTo">
      <input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search"/>
    </div>
    <div class="nextTo">
      <input type="button" name="lockBtn" id="lockBtn" value="Unlock" style="display:none" />
    </div>
    <div class="nextTo">
      <span id="searchMsg" class="msgMainBox"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the divs around the input tags? Also, `<input>` does not use or need a closing slash.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the element absolute position to avoid having the push effect. And for small screen it will go to the bottom:

```js
$('#searchBtn').on('click', searchFun);

function searchFun() {
  var menuVal = $.trim($('#menu').val()),
    searchFldVal = $.trim($('#searchFld').val());

  if (!searchFldVal) {
    $('#searchMsg').addClass("error").show().text('This field is required.').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow').queue(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("error").dequeue();
    });
  } else if (searchFldVal.length < 3) {
    $('#searchMsg').addClass("error").show().text('You must enter at least 3 characters to search on.').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow').queue(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("error").dequeue();
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Search record.');
  }
}
```

```css
section.mainBox {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #000099;
}

div#Container {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #B0C4DE;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
}

div.nextTo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

div.nextTo:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
}

span.msgMainBox {
  display: none;
  margin: 2px 5px;
  padding: 2px 25px 2px 35px;
}

span.error {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 10px center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
}

span.error {
  color: #D8000C;
  background-color: #FFBABA;
}

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
  div.nextTo:last-child {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="mainBox">
  <div id="Container">
    <div class="nextTo">
      <select name="menu" id="menu">
        <option value="1">Name</option>
        <option value="2">DOB</option>
        <option value="3">City</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="nextTo">
      <input type="text" name="searchFld" id="searchFld" size="24" maxlength="24" value="" title="Maximum size of the field is 24 characters." placeholder="Example: Marco Polo">
    </div>
    <div class="nextTo">
      <input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search">
    </div>
    <div class="nextTo">
      <input type="button" name="lockBtn" id="lockBtn" value="Unlock" style="display:none">
    </div>
    <div class="nextTo">
      <span id="searchMsg" class="msgMainBox"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What would happen if I have another div with the button? I tried that and if I set that div to absolute then message will show over that div.

Comment: @espresso_coffee can you elaborate, i didn't get you :)

Comment: So you see that I have Unlock button that is hidden. Once that show up on the screen everything expands and that's fine but after message showed up Unlock button will disappear with the message box. In that case everything shifts. So I tried to set Unlock button div to absolute but in that case message will show over the button.

Comment: @espresso_coffee got it ! in this case you have to adjust value of left/right ... or add a margin left to the message box so that i doesn't overlay the button

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the *positioning*, some modifications to `margin`s and `padding` and `@media` queries which, when screen width gets too narrow, display the error message below and horizontally centered:

```js
$('#searchBtn').on('click',searchFun);

function searchFun(){
  var menuVal = $.trim($('#menu').val()),
 searchFldVal = $.trim($('#searchFld').val());
  
  if(!searchFldVal){
  $('#searchMsg').addClass("error").show().text('This field is required.').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow').queue(function(){
      $(this).removeClass("error").dequeue();
  });
 }else if(searchFldVal.length < 3){
  $('#searchMsg').addClass("error").show().text('You must enter at least 3 characters to search on.').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow').queue(function(){
      $(this).removeClass("error").dequeue();
  });
 }else{
    console.log('Search record.');
  }
}
```

```css
section.mainBox{
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 0;
 background-color: white;
 border: 2px solid #000099;
}
div#Container {
  position: relative; /* added */
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #B0C4DE;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
}
div.nextTo {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
span.msgMainBox {
 display: none; 
 margin: 2px 5px; 
 padding: 2px 25px 2px 35px;
}
span.error {
 border: 1px solid;
  /* added */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* vertically centered */
  margin: 0 5px; /* modified */
  padding: 0 5px; /* modified */
  /***/
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 10px center;
 border-radius: 3px;
 display: block;
}
span.error {
 color: #D8000C;
 background-color: #FFBABA;
}
/* added */
@media screen and (max-width: 630px) { /* adjust to your needs */
  span.error {
    top: calc(100% + 5px); /* + 5px "margin-top" */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* horizontally centered */
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="mainBox">
  <div id="Container">
    <div class="nextTo">
      <select name="menu" id="menu">
        <option value="1">Name</option>
        <option value="2">DOB</option>
        <option value="3">City</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="nextTo">
      <input type="text" name="searchFld" id="searchFld" size="24" maxlength="24" value="" title="Maximum size of the field is 24 characters." placeholder="Example: Marco Polo" />
    </div>
    <div class="nextTo">
      <input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search"/>
    </div>
    <div class="nextTo">
      <input type="button" name="lockBtn" id="lockBtn" value="Unlock" style="display:none" />
    </div>
    <div class="nextTo">
      <span id="searchMsg" class="msgMainBox"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```